# Using the clicks/impressions list from Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, performance, impressions, clicks

`Google Search Console → Performance → Queries`
shows these in the clicks/impressions list for my site:

```
non A Cs                   2,066  7,181
non-A Cs                     679  2,410
non-A C                      143  1,408
non A C list                 117    272
non-A                        106  1,210
what are non A Cs             99    327
non A Cs example              95    261
non A C                       93    503
non A                         64    848
what are non-A Cs             56    151
non-A C list                  46     97
what is non A Cs              36    106
list of non A Cs              35    111
what is non-A Cs              27     62
A and non A Cs example        26    188
what is a non A Cs example    20     47
example of non A Cs           19     54
examples of non A Cs          19     51
what is non A Cs              36    106
list of non A Cs              35    111
what is non-A Cs              27     62
A and non A Cs example        26    188
non A symbols                 20     85
what is a non A Cs example    20     47     
example of non A Cs           19     54
examples of non A Cs          19     51
non A Cs table                 6     37
nonA Cs                        6     31
what is a non-A C              5      9
list of non-A Cs               4     18
```

where "A" and "C" are two of my common keywords.

The searches are effectively asking for the same thing, and finding it, but all in slightly different ways.

**Is there anything useful that could or should be done with this information?**

(*This is just an example for the general question, chosen because there were so many variations of the same search.  If it makes any difference, pretend the numbers are actually much larger.*

*And note that I'm not asking about the click/impression ratio either.
The key thing is the large number of similar queries.*)

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding of your website semantic, there can't be useful answer for this question.

It is possible, that you can see potential for some of this keywords, if you try to make analysis of keyword ranking and CTR. But from impressions and click there is no useful conclusion can be made.